# Remove Button Text If There Isn't Enough Space

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm working with an item template that should display one or more buttons per item. There are three buttons that I want to be displayed on a horizontal line. Each button has an icon and some text.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button x:Name="LeftButton"
          Text="Left Button"
          ImageSource="left.png"
          HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
  <Button x:Name="CenterButton"
          Text="Center Button"
          ImageSource="center.png"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
  <Button x:Name="RightButton"
          Text="Right Button"
          ImageSource="right.png"
          HorizontalOptions="End"/>
</Grid>
```

This is working good so far. The three buttons display the icon and text and they are aligned left, center and right respectively.

Now, I want the buttons to only display the icons, if the container is not wide enough to display all the text. As far as I understand MVVM, this should be the responsibility of the View.

My intended solution would be something like this:

```
public partial class ItemTemplate : ContentView
// ContentView is our implementation of a UI element.
{
  public ItempTemplate()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    SizeChanged += HandleSizeChanged;
  }

  private void HandleSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (/* not enough space */)
    {
      LeftButton.Text = string.Empty;
      CenterButton.Text = string.Empty;
      RightButton.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
      LeftButton.Text = "Left Button";
      CenterButton.Text = "Center Button";
      RightButton.Text = "Right Button";
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to know if the container is wide enough for all three button? If possible, I'd like to use a dynamic solution, because the button text will eventually be translated.

Comment: I think you need to calculate the string width at platform project level https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/182568/calculate-the-maximum-label-text-length

Comment: If your interface can get small enough that only the images can show up can't you always simply use the images without text ? In `winform` this is very easy to do with the string renderer but I am curious to see with `xaml` what is the solution

Comment: "Container not wide enough" means the text would change dynamically to affect the width, or just the count of buttons matters (fixed text on the button)?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the code into a custom contentview , and decide to hide/show the text in the event `LayoutChanged` according to the container's width .

###### Custom View xaml

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="LeftButton" Grid.Column="0" Text="Left Button"  ImageSource="dots.png"  HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <Button x:Name="CenterButton" Grid.Column="1" Text="Center Button"  ImageSource="dots.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="RightButton" Grid.Column="2" Text="Right Button" ImageSource="dots.png" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    </Grid>
```

###### Custom View code behind

```
  public partial class MyView : ContentView
    {
        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.LayoutChanged += MyView_LayoutChanged;
        }

        private void MyView_LayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var view = sender as View;

            if (view.Width < 200)
            {
                LeftButton.Text = string.Empty;
                CenterButton.Text = string.Empty;
                RightButton.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                LeftButton.Text = "Left Button";
                CenterButton.Text = "Center Button";
                RightButton.Text = "Right Button";
            }
        }
    }
```

---

- Scenario : container is large enough.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsApp"

<local:MyView/>
```

[image]

- Scenario : container is small ,wrapped inside another layout .

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Start"  WidthRequest="199" >
        <local:MyView/>
 </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a custom button implementation (mostly because I needed some other additional features).

The custom button contains an Image and a Label. In addition to the standard button features I need, I added these methods to the code-behind:

```
public void ExpandText() {
  Label.IsVisible = true;
}

public void CollapseText() {
  Label.IsVisible = false;
}

public bool IsTextCollapsed() {
  return !Label.IsVisible;
}

public double GetWidthAsExpanded() {
  return Image.Width + Label.Width;
}
```

In the container's code-behind I check if the button's width fits within its container and collapse/expand accordingly. For that to work, I added containers for each button.

```
public ItemTemplate() {
  InitializeComponent();
  LayoutChanged += HandleLayoutChanged;
}

private static void HandleLayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!(sender is ItemTemplate itemTemplate))
  {
    return;
  }
  if (itemTemplate.ButtonContainerLeft.Width > itemTemplate.ButtonLeft.GetWidthAsExpanded()
    && itemTemplate.ButtonContainerCenter.Width > itemTemplate.ButtonCenter.GetWidthAsExpanded()
    && itemTemplate.ButtonContainerRight.Width > itemTemplate.ButtonRight.GetWidthAsExpanded())
  {
    ExpandAllButtons(itemTemplate);
  }
  else
  {
    CollapseAllButtons(itemTemplate);
  }
}
```

Because I added `ExpandText` and `CollapseText` earlier, I don't have to "remember" what the text inside the button was, because I just collapse the label within the button. `GetWidthAsExpanded` will always return the necessary width of the button, even if it is collapsed.

side-note 1: I could've just added the width-check within the custom button implementation, but not every `ItemTemplate` has all buttons and if any label is collapsed, all labels should be collapsed.

side-note 2: I needed button containers either way, because the left button will either be "Mark as Read" or "Mark as Unread" depending on the state of the `ItemTemplate` data context. So there are actually two buttons in the first container.